# inverse of symmetric matrix is not symmetric in Julia

Tags: matrix, julia, linear-algebra

I am using Julia version 0.6.2 and I am facing this problem.

```
mat = zeros(6, 6)
for i = 1 : 6
    for j = 1 : 6
        mat[i, j] = exp(-(i - j)^2)
    end
end
issymmetric(mat)
issymmetric(inv(mat))
```

And the output is

```
Main> issymmetric(mat)
true
Main> issymmetric(inv(mat))
false
```

I also tried the following Matlab code

```
mat = zeros(6, 6);
for i = 1 : 6
    for j = 1 : 6
        mat(i, j) = exp(-(i - j)^2);
    end
end
issymmetric(mat)
issymmetric(inv(mat))
```

And the output is

```
logical 1
logical 1
```

Comment: Numerically it almost never is perfectly symmetric. MATLAB is probably putting a tolerance on its check to ignore "floating point difference" for symmetric.

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas I am using MvNormal function in Julia which will check whether if the given matrix is symmetric. So does it mean that I need to convert this issymetric matrix manually to a symmetric matrix?

Comment: Also posted here: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/inverse-of-a-symmetric-matrix-is-not-symmetric-in-julia/10132

Comment: @David BTW, you can put the construction into one comprehension: `[exp(-(i - j)^2) for i = 1:6, j = 1:6]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apart from manually making the matrix symmetric as you propose, e.g. taking the average of matrix and its transpose like

```
A = inv(mat)
(A+A.')/2
```

probably a cleaner way is

```
smat = Symmetric(mat)
B = inv(smat)
```

now `B` (as well as `smat`) passes `issymmetric`. Moreover, the fact that it is symmetric is ensured on type level (`Symmetric`) - some functions might take advantage of this additional information. This is exactly what `inv` does for `smat`.

EDIT: the question was also posted on [Discourse](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/inverse-of-a-symmetric-matrix-is-not-symmetric-in-julia/10132/4), where you can find additional discussion about the performance of `Symmetric`.